# System Generator error: "The inputs to this block cannot all be constant"

Tags: matlab, vhdl, simulink, fpga, xilinx

I am reading the article ([attached file](http://ecad.tu-sofia.bg/et/2014/ET2014/AJE_2014/108-I_Pandiev2.pdf)) and making VCO circuit (Charged balance) to model on Matlab/Simulink using System Generator. I get some error and I don't know how to fix it. At one-shot timer module when I run, it notifies:

```
Error 0001: The inputs to this block cannot all be constant.
Block: 'VCO_v2/one-shot timer '
```

**This is my diagram**
[image]

**This is the error I encounter**
[image]

[**This is my VCO file I simulink**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=172CUbLsXnMjspolOVp9zESr6GT7bK4Wn)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you :> But if my reputation is not enough to post the image, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You've attached two entities. I'm assuming you're using `oneshot` v1.

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity oneshot is
    port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
            ce : in STD_LOGIC;
            trigger : in STD_LOGIC;
            delay : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
            pulse : out STD_LOGIC :='0');
end oneshot;

architecture Behavioral of oneshot is
    signal count: INTEGER range 0 to 255; -- count variable
    signal flag : STD_LOGIC := '0'; -- count variable
begin
    process (flag,clk,delay)
    begin
        -- wait for trigger leading edge
        if trigger = '1' then
            count <= to_integer(unsigned(delay));
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if count > 0 then
                pulse <= '1';
                count <= count - 1;
            else
                pulse <= '0';
            --flag <='0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

So what's the `flag` signal doing there? Why is it in the sensitivity list? Why is there an unused `ce` input?

But let's look at the `oneshot_config.m` file. The error message originates from there:

```matlab
function setup_as_single_rate(block,clkname,cename) 
    inputRates = block.inputRates; 
    uniqueInputRates = unique(inputRates); 
    if (length(uniqueInputRates)==1 & uniqueInputRates(1)==Inf) 
        block.addError('The inputs to this block cannot all be constant.'); 
        return; 
    end 
    if (uniqueInputRates(end) == Inf) 
        hasConstantInput = true; 
        uniqueInputRates = uniqueInputRates(1:end-1); 
    end 
    if (length(uniqueInputRates) ~= 1) 
        block.addError('The inputs to this block must run at a single rate.'); 
        return; 
    end 
    theInputRate = uniqueInputRates(1); 
    for i = 1:block.numSimulinkOutports 
        block.outport(i).setRate(theInputRate); 
    end 
    block.addClkCEPair(clkname,cename,theInputRate); 
    return;
```

And that is called here

```matlab
if (this_block.inputRatesKnown)
    setup_as_single_rate(this_block,'clk','ce')
end  % if(inputRatesKnown)
```

So the matlab code checks the `inputRates` of all inputs of `this_block` input. It has concluded that all the inputs are constant (you have no variable inputs to you system) and it has concluded that this will not work. This is because it tries to automatically determine the clock frequency from its inputs, which is impossible with constants.

So you'lll have to configure the clock rate manually. You could modify the `oneshot_config.m`. But probably you can assign a rate to the constant block. It should be something like `block.outport.setRate(...);` <-- some clock rate. Check the System Generator user guide.

I don't have System Generator installed on my Matlab pc, so I cannot check this.

Comment: thank you @JHBonarius. You're right, the file code has some unnecessary thing as flag singal. I fixed it, but input 'ce' is necessary when the black box has clk signal (i read in System Generator user guide.). i 'll config clock rate as you said :))

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for this problem. Just change constant block of Matlab instead of using constant block of Xilinx.
[image]